# Animate list element to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using Angular version one, I had created lists of posts in my news feed. Each of the post consists of several action buttons. When I hit button X, the post will bump up to the top. It works same way as [OpenStudy](http://openstudy.com/).

---

**Illustration**

Post#1 ---------------------------------------------------> Post#4

Post#2 ---------------------------------------------------> Post#1

Post#3 ---------------------------------------------------> Post#2

Post#4 (When button triggered in Post#4)------> Post#3

Post#5 ---------------------------------------------------> Post#5

---

**Button X**

```
<li>
   <a id="bump-btn" href="javascript:void(0);">
     <i class="fa fa-gavel" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </a>
</li>
```

How can I create such an animation effect in AngularJS?

Answer (score 0):

You can see http://www.nganimate.org/ or you can use native js animation